# Limitation execution time in linux VM

Tags: python, linux, cron

Does Linux have any time limit for running a python code? I have a code that I need to run everyday in and its execution takes ~3 hours.

When I turn on the linux SSH, the cronjob will run until the end but if I turn off my pc, I don't have idea why it didn't run the code until the end. It stops somewhere. Can anyone help me to provide the code on how to see the cron log and is Linux got execution time?

Here is my crontab code:

```
0 10 * * * /home/user/bin/python /home/user/main.py
```

Comment: First observation: you are missing the leading `/` on both instances of `home`

Comment: And to get the output of cron run jobs check out https://superuser.com/a/122255/155516

Comment: @SamBob yes2.. i wrongly put the code here. but in my code got `/ `

Answer (score 1):

There's no time limit for cron jobs in Linux by default.

To find a reason why your code execution stops at a certain point you need to get some logs.

First check if there's anything in the `syslog` file:  `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`.

If you don't find anything that explains why your script stops then try to do some debugging work. Redirect script output (`stdout` & `stderr`) to a file; for example:

```
0 10 * * * /home/user/bin/python /home/user/main.py >> /path/to/my/logfile.log 2>&1
```

You can always run the script manually with `python /home/user/main.py >> /path/to/my/logfile.log 2>&1` and then analyse the logfile. Or even run it without redirecting anytyhing to a logfile and watch the screen.